# GCM - why im getting NULL in onMessageReceived?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

im using google cloud messaging and i successfully send push notification. the only problem i have is that the method onMessageReceived always gets null.
i can tell by the log, it shows me null. im sending from the server to the user and thats what i get

---

for example
       **04-16 12:29:17.231 19637-19705/com.world.bolandian.watchme

           D/MyGcmListenerService: Message: null**

**This is my server code**

```
 package jdbc;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.net.URLEncoder;

 import javax.sound.midi.SysexMessage;

 import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
 import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
 import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

 public class GcmSender {
    private static final int GCM_RETRIES = 2;

  public void sendGooglePushNotification(String token, String type, String data, String serverApiKey) {

    // Create Message
    Message.Builder builder = new Message.Builder().delayWhileIdle(true);

    try {
        builder.addData(Params.TYPE_MESSAGE, URLEncoder.encode(type, "UTF-8"));
        builder.addData(Params.DATA_MESSAGE, URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Message message = builder.build();

    // Create Sender
    Sender sender = new Sender(serverApiKey);

    // Sending Message with Sender to the list of users.
    try {

        Result rs=sender.send(message, token, GCM_RETRIES);
        String ans=rs.toString();
        System.out.println(ans);

        //System.out.println("notification sent");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Failed to Send Message.

        }

    }
 }
```

**And this is the Android code**

```
 package com.world.bolandian.watchme;

 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.RingtoneManager;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
 import android.util.Log;

 import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

 public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

  private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

   /**
   * Called when message is received.
   *
   * @param from SenderID of the sender.
   * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
   *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
   */
  // [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    /**
     * Production applications would usually process the message here.
     * Eg: - Syncing with server.
     *     - Store message in local database.
     *     - Update UI.
     */

    /**
     * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
     * that a message was received.
     */
    sendNotification(message);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
 *
 * @param message GCM message received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentTitle("ALERT")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =

            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
   }
 }
```

I do get the GCM Message but without the message (data) that i send from the server. and on the log it shows me null.
do you guys have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Message.Builder builder = new Message.Builder().addData("message", "Your string here").delayWhileIdle(true);
```

OR

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("message", "Your string here").delayWhileIdle(true).build();
```

In server side you need to add data to the message you should add data with key and value then you will get it in android like that , in your code you wait data from key "message" in android while no send it from the server

Comment: im sorry but maybe im doing something wrong, but **Message message = new Message.Builder().addData("message", "Your string here").build()**  gets error for it. my code with the builder is not right?

Comment: Message.Builder builder = new Message.Builder().addData("message", "Your string here").delayWhileIdle(true);
it get error ?

Comment: it worked! thanks 
Message.Builder builder = new Message.Builder().addData("message", "Your string here").delayWhileIdle(true)

Comment: very good man you are welcome by the way you can add any data for example addData("message1","yourfirststring")
.addData("othermessage","otherstrings")
.addData("anykeyname",any data) and for sure get it in android with the same keys  
you understand ?